# create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog returning zero results

Tags: pyspark, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I'm trying to create a dynamic glue dataframe from an athena table but I keep getting an empty data frame.

- The athena table is part of my glue data catalog
- The `create_dynamic_frame_method` call doesn't raise any error. I tried loading a random table and it did complain just as a sanity check.
- I know the Athena table has data, since querying the exact same table using Athena returns results
- The table is an external json, partitioned table on s3

I'm using pyspark as shown below:

```
import sys
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext

# Create a Glue context
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

# Create a DynamicFrame using the 'raw_data' table
raw_data_df = 
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="***", 
table_name="raw_***")

 # Print out information about this data, im getting zero here
 print "Count:  ", raw_data_df.count()

#also getting nothing here
raw_data_df.printSchema()
```

Anyone facing the same issue ? Could this be a permissions issue or a glue bug since no errors are raised?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several poorly documented features/gotchas in Glue which is sometimes frustrating.

I would suggest to investigate the following configurations of your Glue job:

1. Does the S3 bucket name has aws-glue-* prefix?
2. Put the files in S3 folder and make sure the crawler table definition is on folder
   rather than actual file.

I have also written a blog on [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/my-top-5-gotchas-working-aws-glue-tanveer-uddin/) about other Glue gotchas if that helps.

Comment: Thank you @Tanveer for your answer. Both suggestions check out for me unfortunately. My table is not created using a glue crawler, rather using a straight up DDL . I maintain the partitions by manually adding them since crawling the data takes 1-2 hours versus near-realtime if I want to do it on demand. Thanks for sharing your blog as well! Please let me know if you have further suggestions.

Comment: Hi Fadi, what about the 2 suggestions above? Did you try/check them? I would suggest please create a bucket e.g. aws-glue-test, create a folder, move one small file there, create your DDL on top of the folder, and then run glue job to see if that works.

Comment: Thank you! spent 2hr searching for clues

Answer (score 2):

Do you have subfolders under the path where your Athena table points to? `glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog` does not recursively read the data. Either put the data in the root of where the table is pointing to or add `additional_options = {"recurse": True}` to your `from_catalog` call.

credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56873939/5112418